# why does my program not print line 9 and instead prints line 7?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

If created this program to only print when the condition is equivalent to the variable age which should've resulted in the final statement to be printed however once I ran the program it instead printed the second last statement which prints out close instead of perfect. I've to figure it out but I couldn't

```py
age = 7
if age == 9:
    print('too old')
elif age == 5:
    print('too young')
elif age == 6 or 8:
    print('close')
elif age == 7:
    print('yes, perfect')
```

Comment: Since `8` is true, `age == 6 or 8` is true. Perhaps you meant `age == 6 or age == 8`?

Comment: `age == 6 or 8` is equivalent to `(age == 6) or (8)`, so it returns `True`. Change it to `age == 6 or age == 8`

Answer (score 0):

8 is truthy.

try this:

```py
age = 7
if age == 9:
    print('too old')
elif age == 5:
    print('too young')
elif age == 6 or age == 8:
    print('close')
elif age == 7:
    print('yes, perfect')
```

Answer (score 0):

you must repeat the condition when using "or"

```
age = 7
if age ==9:
    print('too old')
elif age ==5:
    print('too young')
elif age == 6 or age == 8:
    print('close')
elif age==7:
    print('yes, perfect')
```

Comment: if the solution is correct, accept it